# Which algorithm from petgraph will find the shortest path from A to B?

Tags: rust, petgraph

I have a directional graph and want to find the shortest path from node A to node B. I searched on [crates.io](https://crates.io/) and found [petgraph](https://github.com/bluss/petgraph) which looks like the most popular crate. It [implements a number of algorithms](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.4/petgraph/algo/index.html), but none of them solve my task. Did I miss something?

For example, [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.4/petgraph/algo/fn.dijkstra.html) returns path costs, but which path has the minimum cost? The [Bellman-Ford algorithm](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.4/petgraph/algo/fn.bellman_ford.html) returns path costs
and nodes, but no paths.

This is the simplest way I found to print a path from the graph:

```
extern crate petgraph;
use petgraph::prelude::*;
use petgraph::algo::dijkstra;

fn main() {
    let mut graph = Graph::<&str, i32>::new();
    let a = graph.add_node("a");
    let b = graph.add_node("b");
    let c = graph.add_node("c");
    let d = graph.add_node("d");

    graph.extend_with_edges(&[(a, b, 1), (b, c, 1), (c, d, 1), (a, b, 1), (b, d, 1)]);
    let paths_cost = dijkstra(&graph, a, Some(d), |e| *e.weight());
    println!("dijkstra {:?}", paths_cost);

    let mut path = vec![d.index()];
    let mut cur_node = d;

    while cur_node != a {
        let m = graph
            .edges_directed(cur_node, Direction::Incoming)
            .map(|edge| paths_cost.get(&edge.source()).unwrap())
            .min()
            .unwrap();
        let v = *m as usize;
        path.push(v);
        cur_node = NodeIndex::new(v);
    }

    for i in path.iter().rev().map(|v| graph[NodeIndex::new(*v)]) {
        println!("path: {}", i);
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, I need to calculate the path myself based on result of
`dijkstra`.

I believe that if I implement `dijkstra` by myself (basing my implementation on [dijkstra.rs](https://github.com/bluss/petgraph/blob/0.4.4/src/dijkstra.rs)), and uncomment the lines with `predecessor`, and return `predecessor`, the final variant will be faster because the answer will be something like `predecessor[predecessor[d]]`.

Comment: By your last sentences, you seem to lack an understanding of the Dijkstra and Bellman-Ford algorithms. I would advise you to study them and their outcomes first.

Comment: @E_net4 I don't understand you, I look at implementation of Dijkstra (https://github.com/bluss/petgraph/blob/master/src/dijkstra.rs), they just comment hashmap that contains resulted path, and not return this path. How knowledge of Dijkstra implementation can help me?

Comment: Please include what you have tried in your question. If there is a problem with a specific API, do point it out.

Comment: I suggest you take an extra look at the documentation on `petgraph::algo::dijkstra`, which you linked :)

Comment: @MartinHaTh I look several times, I can not see answer. I added code to explain why.

Comment: @user1244932 The key sentences are: (1) "Compute the length of the shortest path from start to every reachable node."; This implies that this implementation doesn't only give you the path from your A to your B, but from your A to *any* B.  (2) "Returns a HashMap that maps NodeId to path cost."; This gives you the means of which you can "get out" the actual cost :)

Comment: @MartinHaTh So can you simplify my code? After call to dijkstra I actually expect to be able to print answer, not `while` loop, search minium and so on.

Comment: please use this algorithm: astar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420605/which-algorithm-from-petgraph-will-find-the-shortest-path-from-a-to-b/46875017#comment80691174_43420605) (by the library's primary author, no less), you can use the A* (`astar`) algorithm:

```
use petgraph::{algo, prelude::*}; // 0.5.1

fn main() {
    let mut graph = Graph::new();

    let a = graph.add_node("a");
    let b = graph.add_node("b");
    let c = graph.add_node("c");
    let d = graph.add_node("d");

    graph.extend_with_edges(&[(a, b, 1), (b, c, 1), (c, d, 1), (a, b, 1), (b, d, 1)]);

    let path = algo::astar(
        &graph,
        a,               // start
        |n| n == d,      // is_goal
        |e| *e.weight(), // edge_cost
        |_| 0,           // estimate_cost
    );

    match path {
        Some((cost, path)) => {
            println!("The total cost was {}: {:?}", cost, path);
        }
        None => println!("There was no path"),
    }
}
```

```
The total cost was 2: [NodeIndex(0), NodeIndex(1), NodeIndex(3)]
```