# Can I implement a trait while capturing the environment?

Tags: rust, closures, traits

I'm trying to implement A* search for Advent of Code 2019 (Yes, Slowpoke, I know). I've started like this:

```
fn find_path(start: Coords, goal: Coords, map: &Vec<Vec<char>>) -> Vec<Coords> {        
    struct Node {
        distance: u32,
        pos: Coords,
    }
    impl PartialEq for Node {
        fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
            self.distance + manhattan(self.pos, goal) == other.distance + manhattan(other.pos, goal)
        }
    }
    ...
    let mut edge = BinaryHeap::new();        
    edge.push(Node{distance: 0, pos: start});
    ...
```

`Coords` is a struct with an `x` and an `y`. The problem here is that I can't use `goal` in the trait, because it's not in scope. A closure would be able to capture it, but I am doubtful whether I can use a closure instead of a `fn` here. If so, what's the syntax? If not, is there a fundamental reason why it can't be done? I wasn't able to find an answer online.

I know the simple solution is to include `goal` in `Node`, but it's redundant because I'll be creating thousands of `Node` during A*, all of which will have the same goal, wasting memory and CPU cycles. In principle, `goal` could be a single global variable, but that's an untidy option.

Even though I'm sure including `goal` in `Node` would work fine in practice, I'd rather not.

Is there another idiomatic way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot capture any environment in an `impl` block. Closures capture the environment, so you cannot use a closure as a function in an `impl` block.

Functions and methods are designed to be called from *any* context, so there's no guarantee that there even is an environment to be captured. The fact that we can declare types, functions, methods, etc. inside of another function is basically a syntax nicety.

I'd probably create a type that wraps `Node` and `goal`:

```
struct Foo(Node, Coord);

impl Foo {
    fn value(&self) -> WhateverType {
        self.0.distance + manhattan(self.0.pos, self.1)
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Foo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
         self.value() == other.value()
    }
}
```

See also:

- [The petgraph crate](https://crates.io/crates/petgraph)
- [Implement graph-like datastructure in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34747464/155423)
- [Which algorithm from petgraph will find the shortest path from A to B?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43420605/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the links. `petgraph` seems useful and I'll keep it in mind, although I wanted to create an A* implementation that didn't require me to explicitly enumerate all nodes from the outset. I have a grid map, the nodes are implicit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I need `PartialEq` is that the `Node`s are subsequently going into a `BinaryHeap`. If the `BinaryHeap` had an option to provide a custom comparator, that would be perfect: I wouldn't need `Node` to be `Ord`, and I could let `goal` reside in that comparator (closure).

It seems this is being considered: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/69454

In the meantime, there's a crate that provides that functionality: https://crates.io/crates/binary-heap-plus

For now, I'm going to accept the overhead of `goal` inside `Node` but it's good to know my options.